# Screen Sharing with Linux Machine Through Login Server -- OSX Yosemite

Tags: macos, ssh, vnc

I have a specific question pertaining to how I can work remotely using my Mac.

The group I work for requires you to go through a "login" portal (a machine that you have to ssh to before accessing any other of the group's machines). The address for that is, say, myname@login.group.edu. I then ssh to the machine where I can work. These are all linux machines. Let's say my work machine is machine.group.edu, and I have the same username (myname) for each (but different passwords). I've set up a VNC portal on the work machine, but not the login computer.

I need to be able to see the desktop from my Mac, running OSX Yosemite (have to use ghostview, which is terribly slow with just X11 forwarding). I can connect using screen sharing, i.e. going to terminal, typing:

```
ssh -options 5901:machine.group.edu:5901 myname@login.group.edu
```

but it always displays the desktop, then cuts out after just a minute (connection refused).

I then tried using Jolly's Fast VNC AND the VNC Viewer for Google Chrome extension, neither of which I could get working. Usually it says "connection refused", or it just spins forever. Is there something I'm doing wrong when connecting via screen sharing? If not, how do I properly enter the network name, ssh options, portal, etc. in Jolly's Fast VNC or VNC Viewer when connecting THROUGH the login machine to a different server?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by **changing window manager from gnome to xfce**, and using normal mac screen sharing protocol.